# Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 ". Failed to read or create install properties file. Failed packages:

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

[in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0DNq.png)

Packages to install: - Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (build-tools;30.0.3)

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 v.30.0.3".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Failed packages:

- Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (build-tools;30.0.3)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.